# Why we need events for callback?

Tags: c#, .net

We can call callback methods using delegates.
For eg,

public delegate bool ContinueProcessing();

// later in code we can write ,

ContinueProcessing cp = new ContinueProcessing(IsDataAvailable);

cp += new ContinueProcessing(IsTransactionComplete);

//later in code defination of methods

bool IsDataAvailable()
{
return true;
}

bool IsTransactionComplete()
{
return true;
}

cp.Invoke() ;

The above call will call two boolean method one after the other. 
Why we need "Events" ?
What is the purpose of "Events" ?

Answer (score 9):

Events are callbacks where you can have multiple subscribers who don't interfere with each other and can't call each other.

Delegates provide the encapsulation of "this is the action I want to take" and events provide the encapsulation of the pub/sub model.

See my [article on events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are very generic. They can be used in any context: within the same class, between classes, in static methods etc.

Events are more specific -- they are specifically designed to be used for one class to subscribe to an event raised by another class.

Delegate is a (kind of) type-safe pointer to a function, whereas event is wrapper around delegate that provides standard interface to Subscribe/Unsubscribe/Raise an event.

Comment: Events only add "Add" and "Remove" methods around delegate. We can achieve everything without mentioning "Events". Why you say Delegates are more generic?

Comment: Delegates are more generic in the sense that they can be used in a wider selection of scenarios. You can do many things with delegates, including implementing events, but with events you can only do one thing: events.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 'event' keyword is a modifier for a delegate declaration that allows it to be included in an interface, constraints it invocation from within the class that declares it, provides it with a pair of customizable accessors (add and remove) and forces the signature of the delegate (when used within the .NET framework).